# ConTeXt: Embed forward referenced figure

Tags: graphics, context, context-mkiv, content-replication

## Background

Looking to recreate the following fancy table of contents where a limited number of images in the ToC are selected at random from all the figures included in the document, without repeating:

[image: Random Images]

This is merely one theme of many that users can generate; other themes do not include thumbnails in the ToC (i.e., the images only appear once). Another theme might reference the images in the index or credits section in the backmatter. Yet another theme might reference the images on the chapter page (providing a random selection of images found later in that chapter).

Note: the above is a quick example; I'm aware that the four images are repeated...

## Example

```
\setupexternalfigures[
  order={svg,pdf,png,jpg},
  location=global,
  wfactor=fit,
] 

\setupcaptions[location=,]

\define[1]\Photograph{%
  \placefigure[]{}{%
    \externalfigure[#1][
      %width=\dimexpr.25\paperwidth
    ]
  }
}

\starttext
  % Thumbnail versions of referenced images are placed above the ToC.
  Table of Contents
  \placecontent

  \startchapter 
  Final board position:
  \Photograph{http://warp.povusers.org/pics/GobanPic.jpg}
  \stopchapter
  \startchapter
  Opening problem #1:
  \Photograph{http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs14/i/2007/091/c/8/Goban_Wall_by_zipper.jpg}
  \stopchapter
  \startchapter
  Opening problem #2:
  \Photograph{http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Goban2.png}
  \stopchapter
  \startchapter
  Close up:
  \Photograph{http://www.bengozen.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/leathergoban05.jpg}
  \stopchapter
\stoptext
```

## Ideas

The algorithm likely requires Lua:

1. Create an array of all `externalfigure` usages in the document.
2. Randomly remove a figure from the document.
3. Update the document to embed the image (scaled and cropped).

Another idea is to create the list of images at the start of every document, before the text. Something like:

```
\def\photo1{http://warp.povusers.org/pics/GobanPic.jpg}
\def\photo2{http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs14/i/2007/091/c/8/Goban_Wall_by_zipper.jpg}
\def\photo3{http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Goban2.png}
\def\photo4{http://www.bengozen.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/leathergoban05.jpg}

\definenumber[photos][way=bytext,prefix=no]
\getnumber[photos]

% Embeds the images in order
\define\Photograph{%
  \placefigure[]{}{%
    \incrementnumber[photos]
    \externalfigure[\photo\getnumber[photos]][
    ]
  }
}


\starttext
  % Thumbnail versions of referenced images are placed above the ToC.
  Table of Contents
  \placecontent

  \startchapter \Photograph \stopchapter
  \startchapter \Photograph \stopchapter
  \startchapter \Photograph \stopchapter
  \startchapter \Photograph \stopchapter
\stoptext
```

## Question

How would you embed a thumbnail version of an image in a document prior to its first reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a comment rather than a complete answer, but I am writing as an answer so that the code is easily understandable.

Firstly, instead of `\def\photo1{....}` and `\Photograph`, I would recommend the following:

```
\useexternalfigure[photo1][http://warp.povusers.org/pics/GobanPic.jpg]
\starttext
...
\externalfigure[photo1]
...
\stopexternalfigure
```

Now, if you are willing to list all the figures upfront, then one possible solution is to create lua table of all figures.

```
\startluacode
userdata = userdata or {}
userdata.figures = {
  ["photo1"] = {http://warp.povusers.org/pics/GobanPic.jpg},
  ["photo2"] = {...},
  ...
}
\stopluacode
```

and then create a lua function that takes a table of figures and calls `\useexternalfigure` (psuedo code, not tested)

```
\startluacode
userdata.initializefigures = function(figures)
  for key, value in pairs(figures) do
    context.useexternalfigure( {key}, {value})
  end
end
\stopluacode
```

Next, define a lua function that scales and includes the figures:

```
\startluacode
userdata.includefigures = function(figures)
  for key,value in pairs(figures) do
     -- randomly select images, if needed
     context.startplacefigure()
        context.externalfigure{key}
     context.stopplacefigure()
  end
end
\stopluacode
```

In the main document (i.e., outside of the ToC), use:

```
\externalfigure[photo1]
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, then first defining the figures with `useexternalfigure` is not necessary if the figures are defined using Lua code? That is, I can define the figures once in the document (using Lua) and then refer to them later using *either* Lua (for the ToC) or ConTeXt (using `\externalfigure` later in the document)? That seems ideal: not having to define the figures twice.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: yes you may do that, but then you will have to type the name of the figures twice. I find it more convenient to use a reference.